# Fails To Send Request has Geographical Location using postman and spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, jpa, point

I am trying to create an object has a point datatype which implemented by spring boot `org.springframework.data.geo.Point`  and save it in the database using JPA . but the request throws invalidDefinitionException exception before even hit the controller

> Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.data.geo.Point]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.data.geo.Point` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 16, column: 9] (through reference chain: com.test.CreationRequest["location"])

CreationRequest Object :

```
public class CreationRequest {
    private String building;
    private Point location;
  
}
```

Postman Request :

> {
> "building":"114",
> "location": {
> "x":30.025622148122764,
> "y": 31.482759761365305
> } }

Comment: Please share Point Class as well, I think it's missing getters/setter and constructor

Comment: Point class is implemented by Spring boot . I am using import org.springframework.data.geo.Point .

Answer (score 1):

To serialize third-party types that do not offer a default constructor or have support for *Jackson* serialization feature, you can:

- Either implement a custom serializer / deserializer for your type and annotate the field where you need to have support for serialization
- or use [*Jackson Mix-In(s)*](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations)

Here down the *Mix-In* annotation approach:

```
abstract class PointMixIn {

  PointMixIn(@JsonProperty("x") int x, @JsonProperty("y") int y) { }

  @JsonProperty("x") abstract int getX();

  @JsonProperty("y") abstract int getY();
  
}
```

You should then update your `ObjectMapper` instance to add support for the mix-in:

```
objectMapper.addMixInAnnotations(org.springframework.data.geo.Point.class, PointMixIn.class);
```

Comment: I've went with basic solution . custom serializer . Thanks man